# Xcode's Storyboard doesn't recognize UIViewController within Swift

Tags: uistoryboard, ios8, xcode6

**Environment:** Xcode 6 Beta 4/iOS 8 SDK

**Scenario:** Original Objective-C project with Swift.

Greetings:

   I'm attempting to hook up a .swift file into an existing Objective-C project.

This particular .swift file contains a UIViewController that is linked to a UIViewController entity within the storyboard.

**Storyboard's attribute snippet:**

[image]

The following is the content of the .swift file:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class RecursionViewController : UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad()  {
        println("{Recursion Swift} viewDidLoad")
    }

    @IBAction func doneAction(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        println("--- {Recursion} doneAction --- ")
    }

}
```

However, upon build, I noticed that the 'RecursionViewController', as define above and linked via the storyboard, is *still unknown*:

```
Unknown class RecursionViewController in Interface Builder file.
```

**Why is this happening?**

Comment: Are they of the same type?  Is recursionviewcontroller a plain viewController, or a TableViewController, or some other type?

Comment: 'recursionViewController' is a plain UIViewController.  Nothing fancy.  See its class definition above.

Comment: 2 years later: Did you figure it out?

Comment: It appeared to be a bug.  After rebuilding from scratch the problem went away. I haven't been able to re-create the problem with newer releases of Xcode/Swift.